# Can I pass values from AJAX post request Without creating a new class for that object, I need to update specific fields

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-boot

**This part is for making the request**
**

I want send an array and 2 other variable data
I Know I can Make use Of @PathVarible annotaion but I want to make secured so is it possible not to use that
**

```
if(arr.length>=1){
           console.log(arr);
           var stored_status = $("#statusselsect").val();
           var selected_status = book_obj.gadBookingStatusMaster.bookingstatusid;
           var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
           var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
            $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
            });
            console.log(book_obj.bookingid);
           if(stored_status == selected_status ){
               alert("Status Must be changed ");
           }else{
               
               var savedata = {
                     'rooms':arr, 
                    'bookingId':book_obj.bookingid,
                    'status':selected_status 
               }
               console.log(JSON.stringify(savedata));
               $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "<%=path %>/gadbook/bookid/updatebooking/",
                    data: JSON.stringify(savedata),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    cache: false,
                  
                    success: function (data) {
                         event.preventDefault();
                        if(data.msgType==true){
                            
                            swal("Successfull!", data.message, "success");
                            
                             $("#submit").prop("disabled", false);
                        
                             
                        }else if(data.msgType==false) {
                            swal("Error!", data.message, "error");
                            
                        }
                       
    
                    }
                });
    
           }
```

**My Java Code But its not correct I failed here**

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/gadbook/bookid/updatebooking/"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
          public AjaxDataTransfer updateBooking(Model model,@RequestParam("rooms")  Array rooms,@RequestBody long bookingId,@RequestBody long status){
    
         
         System.out.println(bookingId);
         return null;
     }
```

**I dont want to create a class , I want to use the data provided and fetch the data later**

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class matching your payload that you are sending and use that as a request object.  Something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/gadbook/bookid/updatebooking/"},method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public AjaxDataTransfer updateBooking(@RequestBody Reservation reservation){
     System.out.println(bookingId);
     return null;
  }
```

Model class

```
  class Reservation {

    int bookingId;
    String status;
    List<String> rooms


    //Getters, Setters
  }
```

Comment: Thank you sir , for the suggestion . Can you advise me if there is other  way around without creating a class. Directly I can get the data like we do in http servelet request